# How to determinate if you need a Right Right rotation or a Right Left rotation

Tags: logic, avl-tree

I am trying to implement an AVL tree and I'm having a hard time knowing when I need a RR or RL rotation (same for LL and LR).

What are the preconditions for each and how are they different. I know when I see a picture of the tree (intuitively) but what are the actual conditions ?

This is a logic problem, no code necessary, thank you.

**What I do know** is it involves the tree being left heavy or right heavy. But how do you determine that ?

Comment: Are you considered with a certain operation, e.g. adding a node to the tree and then maintaining the balance property?

Comment: Both in adding and removing, but if I understand one I imagine the other comes just as easily. I want the tree to maintain it's balance at all times, but since the only time it is modified is by adding or removing an element, I can't see any other moment it's necessary. **But I would prefer to concentrate on adding elements at the moment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be different solutions, but one is as following:

When adding an item recursively, at each recursive call you should keep track of whether that call added the node to the left or right subtree (by letting the add function return it, for example). After the recursive call you check the height invariant. If you find that the it has been violated at that node after the insertion, you will then know the path to the imbalance.

Some (incomplete) pseudo-code:

```
add(item, node):
  if item < node.value //should add to left subtree
    if node.left is empty
      //add item here
    else
      addedLeft := add(item, node.left)
      if node.left.height - node.right.height > 1
        if addedLeft
          //you know the path to the subtree causing the imbalance is LL, do a RR (single-right) rotation
        else
          //path is LR, do a LR (double-right) rotation
  ...
```

The recursive calls will unfold bottom-up from the added node and the general idea is to check at which node the invariant is violated (if any). When that node is discovered, you need to know the path to the subtree causing the imbalance. One must solve that problem somehow, this is one solution.

Comment: so I have to keep track of the path I went while adding the node. Does this mean I need to remember the last 2 paths ? (LL or LR etc) ?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Yes because it is necessary in order to determine what rotation to perform, no because you don't need to "remember" it more than the above pseude code - the logic is here is that if we decide to add the node to the left subtree and the recursive call to add also decides to add the item to its left subtree, the subtree causing the imbalance must be left-left from the current node. Does that help?

Comment: yes, I think I get it. I need to implement this first, but if it does work (meaning I did get what you meant) I will chose your answer, otherwise I'll update the question. Regardless, thank you.